# Binary classification: dataset with a binary output where I can apply logistic regression

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset with binary output. I would prefer it to be something like years of experience, salary, and a binary output like a subscription to a website. This is to create a use case for logistic regression. I looked on glassdoor for [the salaries of data scientists](https://www.glassdoor.fr/Salaires/paris-data-scientist-salaire-SRCH_IL.0,5_IM1080_KO6,20.htm?countryRedirect=true) but it doesn't seem there is an available xhr, and it doesn't look like we have their years of experience neither. I tried to generate it using distributions but I wasn't convinced by the results:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson, truncnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_truncated_normal(mean=0, sd=1, low=0, upp=10):
    return truncnorm(
        (low - mean) / sd, (upp - mean) / sd, loc=mean, scale=sd)
    
years_of_experience = poisson.rvs(mu=4, size=15)
salaries = get_truncated_normal(mean=45000, sd=5000, low=38000, upp=57000).rvs(15)
subscriptions = [random.randint(0,1) for _ in range(0,15)]
data = [[experience, salary, account] for experience, salary, account in zip(years_of_experience, salaries, subscriptions)]
```

Which creates:

[image]

Whereas I'm rather looking for something like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The data related to the yearly Stackoverflow survey (for instance [Developer Survey Results 2019](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019)) seems to fit your description, but you might need to do some data-cleaning. The data can downloaded form here: [Stack Overflow Annual Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey).

Answer (score 0):

The Irvine University has a [large dataset repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php) which is searchable by categories, for example: univariate classification in Business area.

This is one example, about [Bank Marketing](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing):
The classification goal is to predict if the client will subscribe (yes/no) a term deposit.